# Удаление большого количества записей со связанных таблиц Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, big-data, foreign-key, delete

Я разрабатываю социальную сеть. У меня есть много таблиц, и некоторые из них: User, Post, UserAction (в этой таблице я сохраняю пользователя, которому понравился пост). У меня есть связь между User и Post и UserAction. Например, для одного пользователя у нас есть 100 000 постов. И если пользователь решит удалить учетную запись, нам нужно удалить все его посты. Это означает, что мы должны удалить все связанные данные из соответствующих таблиц. Но это займет очень много времени (и, возможно, это заблокирует запросы к таблице, я не помню, есть ли у Postgres механизм concurrent-удаления). Так какие же методы использовать, чтобы очень быстро удалить все эти данные? Большое спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: *если пользователь решит удалить учетную запись, нам нужно удалить все его посты. Это означает, что мы должны удалить все связанные данные из соответствующих таблиц.* А если пользователь потом передумает и попросит восстановить его - откуда будешь данные брать? Подумай хорошенько - может, не надо ничего удалять, а...

Comment: Вот именно, просто пометьте пользователя удаленным и не выводите его посты. И не забудьте, что если вы делаете это в РФ то вы обязаны хранить посты полгода минимум (даже если пользователь удалил сам свой отдельный пост)

Comment: @Akina, я имею в виду кейс, когда он не решит восстановить акк, т.е. пройдёт допустим полгода и он никаких действий не предпринимет

Comment: У Вас что, с местом хранения проблемы? Если нет - [партиционирование](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-partitioning.html) в зубы, актуальное налево, архивное направо.